# Swift unit-testing: Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I have Objective-C project and I decided to write unit test in Swift.

Everything runs normally however I cannot see param values during debugging.

When I set cursor on value I see its name and not value:

[image]

when I try to print it out in `lldb` I get following error:

```
(lldb) po expectedEncryptedStr
warning: Swift error in module AppLibTests.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'AppLibTests' from AST context:
```

I use `Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)`

Any ideas?

**[EDIT]**

When I enter with braking point to Objective-C code - everything works as expected

Comment: Xcode's debugger has lots of bugs -- I run into stuff like this all of the time. If you have a small project that reproduces it, you can open a Radar on http://bugreport.apple.com